# React Native: Can build warnings always be ignored?

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, android-studio, node-modules

Whenever I build a React Native app, I get hundreds of warnings that do not prevent the build from being successful. For example, I almost always see many errors like `The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99.`.

**What I Want To Know:** I ignore these warnings because they're not errors. Is there ever a reason to *not* ignore them? For example, is it possible that even though they don't affect a given build, they might affect a future one and I should try to resolve them now? Or are many of these warnings part of node modules that I can't change, and I should always ignore them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can easily disable them. At the end of my talk I will show you how to do this.

## But:

> Warnings can sometimes be very helpful.

However, when you are developing your project, they are very annoying and cause console clutter and confusion.

Whenever I am developing a component, I disable alerts at the beginning. And after the development of a component is finished, I reactivate the alerts to be notified that my component performance is improving.

For example, React says you should always use an `key` attribute in `map` statements. But well, sometimes I forget to do it. Do not insert `key` is not a mistake. But for reasons (which are not allowed here) it is better to use it.

So I suggest you do the same. This can be done simply with the following command:

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

For example

```
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
     render() {
          console.disableYellowBox = true;
          return (...);
     }
}
```

Also you can include `console.disableYellowBox = true;` after your imports.